# Parse error in pattern x * y (of case statement)

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

I have this code:

```
module BalancedTwoDozenMultDrill where
import BalancedTwoDozenLib
myRandoms :: Int -> IO [Int]
myRandoms n = let x = 24^n `div` 2 in randomRs (-x,x) <$> getStdGen
drill :: [Int] -> IO ()
drill (x:y:rs) = do
    putStr $ showInt x ++ " × " ++ showInt y ++ " = "
    a <- getLine
    case a of
        "" -> return ()
        showInt (x * y) -> do   -- <= here
            putStrLn "Correct"
            drill rs
        _ -> do
            putStrLn $ "Wrong; " ++ showInt (x * y)
            drill rs
main :: IO [Int]
main = drill =<< myRandoms =<< readLn
```

and get error:

```
BalancedTwoDozenMultDrill.hs:11:18: Parse error in pattern: x * y
```

However, replacing part of the case statement with:

```
    -- ...stuff
    let i = showInt (x * y)
    case a of
        "" -> return ()
        i -> do
        -- stuff...
```

Makes it parse (it goes to “not in scope” errors, which I can fix). The only reason I see for the first fragment being wrong is that there is function application going on. Is it true that I can't use ordinary function application for the alternatives in a case statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have a pattern in a case statement, it has to follow the same rules as that in pattern matching on function arguments.  Only literals, constructors, and the wildcard `_` can be matched on, not function applications.  Instead, you could do something more like

```
a <- getLine
let xyStr = showInt (x * y)        -- Avoid recomputation with a let binding
when (not $ null a) $ do
    if a == xyStr
        then do
            putStrLn "Correct"
            drill rs
        else do
            putStrLn $ "Wrong; " ++ xyStr
            drill rs
```

You'll need to import `when` from `Control.Monad`, though.

---

The reason why you have to follow the same rules in case statements as in pattern matching in function definitions is because the compiler actually converts something like

```
head :: [a] -> a
head (x:xs) = x
head _ = error "Prelude.head: empty list"
```

Into

```
head :: [a] -> a
head list = case list of
    (x:xs) -> x
    _      -> error "Prelude.head: empty list"
```

The only reason we have the former version is convenience, it often makes for prettier looking code.

[This](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) link should be able to give you a more thorough explanation as to what is and isn't valid pattern matching constructs.

---

The other problem you had was trying to replace `showInt (x * y)` with `i` where `let i = showInt (x * y)`.  When you do this, you first bind the value `showInt (x * y)` to the name `i`, then in your case statement you have the patterns

```
"" -> ...
i  -> ...
_  -> ...
```

So now your *pattern is `i`*, and it will act like a catch-all pattern after `""`.  This rebinds the name `i` for the scope of that case statement.

A good rule to keep in mind is that you can't pattern match against a value obtained at run time, you have to check with equality or other comparison operations.

Comment: This is the answer, but the reason doesn't make sense. It says that the patterns allowed for functions must be a subset of the patterns allowed for case statements, not that they must be equal.

Comment: I've noticed what I was doing wrong now. I was trying to shadow `x` and `y`, not use their previous values. Can you add that to your answer?

Comment: @JamesWood I guess you could put it that way, but syntactically the compiler views case patterns and argument patterns as the same thing.  A more logically correct statement would have been "the reason why you have to follow the same rules in function definitions as in case statements is because the compiler converts function definitions to case statements", but AFAIK patterns are patterns in Haskell, they're treated the same everywhere you can use them.  This includes let statements, monadic bind operations, and list comprehensions as well.

Comment: @JamesWood Ah, yes, I see that more subtler problem now.  I'll add that to my answer as well.

Comment: @bheklilr There are some slight variations from place to place, though. E.g. `let` and `where` patterns are lazy by default, while the others are strict. And function/lambda parameter patterns require slightly different parenthesizing because you can have more than one in a row.

Answer (score 4):

Although an answer already accepted I'd just mention there is a bit tricky way how use a boolean expressions in a `case` expression - by using guards:

```
   case () of
       _
        | a == "" -> return ()
        | showInt (x * y) -> do   -- <= here
            putStrLn "Correct"
            drill rs
        | otherwise -> do
            putStrLn $ "Wrong; " ++ showInt (x * y)
            drill rs
```

Comment: That can be "improved" in either of two different directions: (1) `case a of "" -> return (); _ | showInt ...` (2) Using the new [multi-way if](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if) extension.